# Probability of [X<a + bZ, X<Y, X>Z]?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to derive the following probability:

$\Pr \left[ {X < a + bZ,X < Y,X > Z} \right]$

where X,Y, and Z follow exponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_x$, $\lambda_y$, and $\lambda_z$, respectively. I tried to use conditional probability approach. I also tried to find the region based on which the above probability can be evaluated by a triple integral. But I failed.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are $X,Y,Z$ independent?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets start with $Z$ and say that $Z$ can be arbitrary positive number, then $X$ must be in interval $(Z,a+bZ)$ and $Y$ must be interval $(X,\infty)$. So you can derive the probability using

$$\Pr \left[ {X < a + bZ,X < Y,X > Z} \right] == 
\int_0^\infty \int_z^{a+bz} \int_x^{\infty} f(x,y,z) dy dx dz,$$

where $f$ is joint density of $X,Y,Z$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do we need to consider the case that $Y < a + bZ$, in which X should be in interval (Z,Y)?

Comment: This case is already considered. I think the easiest way to determine the desired area is: pick $z$ $\to$ pick $x$ $\to$ pick $y$. Of course you can change the orders of integrals however you also have to change the limits of the area.

Comment: Thank you very much. I derived analytic expression, which is the same with simulated result. ^^.

Comment: Dear, 

How about this probability: $Pr[Y<a + bZ,Y<X,Z<X]$?

Can we proceed as follows:

$\Pr \left[ {Y < a + bZ,Y < X,Z < X} \right] = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\int\limits_0^x {\int\limits_0^{a + bz} {{f_{X,Y,Z}}\left( {x,y,z} \right)dydzdx} } }$, where I pick X, then Z, and finally pick Y.

Comment: For $a>0$ and $b>1$ we have $\int\limits_{z = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_{y = z}^{a + bz} {\int\limits_{x = y}^\infty  {f\left( {x,y,z} \right)dxdydz} } }  + \int\limits_{z = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_{y = 0}^z {\int\limits_{x = z}^\infty  {f\left( {x,y,z} \right)dxdydz} } } $